# insertar un archivo js, con Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-blade

tengo un formulario en el cual hago una búsqueda de un elemento por medio de ajax, si el código esta dentro de la vista.blade.php funciona bien , pero si lo quiero poner "por cuestiones de orden " en un archivo .js me da error

```
$('#cliente').keyup(function () {
    var query = $(this).val();
    if (query != '') {
        var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('ventas.fetch')}}",
            method: "POST",
            data: { query: query, _token: _token },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ListaClientes').fadeIn();
                $('#ListaClientes').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: esto es porque dentro del archivo js no se puede obtener el valor de `{{route('ventas.fetch')}}` ya que el cast es solo para plantillas blade podrias crear una funcion llamada `function geturl(url)` y la llamas desde la platilla blade pasandole el url `geturl("{{route('ventas.fetch')}}");`

Answer (score 1):

es porque `{{  }}` este comando solo funciona dentro de `*.blade.php` y no en un `script.js` que esta fuera de tal archivo, en tal caso podrias guardar la `url` en un variable  es decir:

**app.blade.php**

```
/*
   resto de codigo
*/
@push('js')
<script>
    //Captura url para evitar {{}}
    var uri='<php echo url("/") ?>';

    //Agrega token a todas nuestas peticiones xhr [ajax,axios,fetch] 
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
</script>
@endpush
```

> @push : es una equita en caso de usar herencia de plantillas, si no lo usa, puedes escribir directamente la etiqueta `<script>`

**script.js**

```
$('#cliente').keyup(function () {
var query = $(this).val();
if (query != '') {
    $.ajax({
        url: uri+"/ventas/fetch",
        method: "POST",
        data: { query: query},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#ListaClientes').fadeIn();
            $('#ListaClientes').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

});